# PostgreSql correct number of field

Tags: database, postgresql

I would like your opinion. I have a table with 120 VARCHAR fields where I will have to hire about 1,000 records per month for at least 10 years, with a total number of 240,000 records.
I could divide the fields into multiple tables but I'd rather keep it that way. Do you think I will have problems in the future?
Thank you

Comment: You have 120 different varchar-columns? Or do you mean a random number of varchar-columns with the size of 120?

Comment: Yes, i have 120 different varchar-columns into a single table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the data of the columns is following a certain logic, keep it flat. Which means that I would let it that way. Otherwise separate it into multiple tables. I depents on your data.

I worked once worked with medical data where one table contained over 100 columns, but all these columns where needed to get a diagnostic result. I don't remember, what exactly it was, because I worked with that data set some years ago. But in that case it would make it more complicated, if the columns would be separated into multiple columns. Logically the data of each column served a certain purpose so it was easier to have them all in the same place (the table).

If you put the columns all together just to be lazy, so that you have to call the table once, I would recommend to separate the columns into different tables to make it more comfortable to work with, and to make the database schema more understandable.

Comment: also in my case are medical data, and split information complicates the procedure. It is not out of laziness that I created as well, but by necessity, I'm just wondering if I can have problems in the future, it is the first time I use a table with many columns.

Comment: Basically I don't see problems there as long as you know how to work with the data. If it is easier to keep that amount of columns in one table, keep it that way. I think it is not that rare when you work with medical data, that you have a lot of columns. But basically there shouldn't be a technical problem I think.